# In what cases are CSS transitions removed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to Javascript, and I have a webpage I'm trying to make that uses the same HTML file, and just cross-fades content instead of redirecting to new pages. I'm using event listeners to know when the current page has faded out and that triggers the new page to come in. Why is it that in the example below, the new pages don't fade in slowly (they just appear suddenly, ignoring the transition property)? Why is the content no longer responding to the CSS transition?

*Edit:* I'll try to clarify what I'm asking here. I'm aware that the `display` feature cannot be transitioned, and that's actually why I'm using the event listener at all. I'm trying to make it so that when the content of one page fades out, the next one fades in in the same place, which I believe cannot be achieved with `visibility`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        
        <!-- CSS -->
        <style>
            /* navagation bar style */
            #navbar {
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #000000;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                height: 36px;
            }
            #navbar a {
                display: inline-block;
                color: #ffffff;
                padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            /* content style*/
            .page {
                padding: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                transition: opacity 1s;
            }
        </style>
        
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {setup()};

            function setup() {
                var page1link = document.getElementById("page1link");
                var page1 = document.getElementById("page1");
                page1.style["opacity"] = "1";

                var page2link = document.getElementById("page2link");
                var page2 = document.getElementById("page2");
                page2.style["opacity"] = "0";
                page2.style["display"] = "none";

                var page3link = document.getElementById("page3link");
                var page3 = document.getElementById("page3");
                page3.style["opacity"] = "0";
                page3.style["display"] = "none";

                page1link.onclick = function() {fade(page1, page2, page3)};
                page2link.onclick = function() {fade(page2, page1, page3)};
                page3link.onclick = function() {fade(page3, page1, page2)};
            }

            function fade(page_1, page_2, page_3) {
                let on_page;
                if (page_2.style["opacity"] != "0") {
                    on_page = page_2
                } else if (page_3.style["opacity"] != "0") {
                    on_page = page_3
                } if (on_page != undefined) {
                    on_page.addEventListener('transitionend', fadePageIn)
                    on_page.style["opacity"] = "0";
                    function fadePageIn() {
                        on_page.style["display"] = "none";
                        page_1.style["display"] = "";
                        page_1.style["opacity"] = "1";
                        on_page.removeEventListener('transitionend', fadePageIn);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <a id="page1link" href="javascript:void(0)">Page 1</a>
            <a id="page2link" href="javascript:void(0)">Page 2</a>
            <a id="page3link" href="javascript:void(0)">Page 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page1">
            page 1 content here
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page2">
            page 2 content here
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page3">
            page 3 content here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer by Mark seems right. Try commenting out the `["display"] = "none"` everywhere its used in the javascript. It won't give you the display you won't but it definitely fixes the issue (fades one, then displays the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate the `display` property. So when you set `opacity` and `display` at the same time, the `opacity` will transition but the `display` value changes immediately.

As an alternative, the `visibility` property can be animated. Interpolation between its values happens at the halfway point, so if you want to make it work with `transition` that might complicate things. But I've had success in the past using CSS animations to change `opacity` and `visibility` at the same time. Using animations like this:

```
@keyframes becomeVisible {
      0% { visibility: visible; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
}
@keyframes becomeHidden {
      0% { visibility: visible; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; }
}


@keyframes fadein {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeout {
      0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew that `display` could not be transitioned, but it was good to hear why that is messing things up here. However, the issue I have with using `visibility` is that objects with no visibility still take up space on the screen, correct? I'm hoping to make it so that content of each page appears in the same position on the screen after this fading stuff if that makes sense.

Comment: That's correct, yes, and it's definitely a drawback of this method. There are a few ways you can take elements out of the flow though, such as by making them `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.

Basically, as Mark points out, you can't animate it because setting the display property isn't possible to animate, thus nullifying your other transitions.

Therefore, as long as you can update the transition-able properties later in the event loop, then it will work as intended. A very easy way to do this is to use a `setTimeout` with 0 time.

```
function transitionEndCallback() {
     oldPage.style["display"] = "none";
     newPage.style["display"] = "block";
     // add the setTimeout somewhere in this function        
     setTimeout(() => {
            page_1.style["opacity"] = "1";
     }, 0)
     on_page.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionEndCallback);
}
```

This way, it gets called in a different event loop callback, but still updates almost immediately afterwards. There maybe a better callback function or feature because it's a bit hacky, but I can verify it works.

Comment: Nice! I'll give this a try soon. I did get it to "work" replacing `display: none` with a combination of `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0`, but the invisible pages cover up content on the screen, making them non-interactive, so I was looking for an alternative.